# Connection checker for Nuxt3 ($nuxt.isOffline)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt2 there were connection checkers

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers/#connection-checker

You could do the following `this.$nuxt.isOffline`

Is there a way to do this with Nuxt3?

I tried looking at `useNuxt()` to see of there was some info in there but do not see anything.

---

My question was also asked on Github discussions: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/4996

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vue's ecosystem is more used with Composition API approach in mind nowadays, hence everything is a bit more decoupled overall.

[VueUse's useOnline](https://vueuse.org/core/useonline/#useonline) is de-facto the best approach overall.

Install it with `yarn add @vueuse/core` and you'll be able to use it right off

```html
<script setup>
import { useOnline } from '@vueuse/core'

const online = useOnline()
</script>

<template>
  <p>Is my website online? {{ online }}</p>
</template>
```

Using Chrome, you can emulate an offline connection and see that the Boolean properly switches to false.

[image]

---

Credits to [manniL on Discord](https://discord.com/channels/473401852243869706/780535774256824350/835525637551685653) as a reminder for that one, I totally forgot about `useOnline()`.

Comment: Also for reference here is the discussion on the Nuxt Github page where the same approach is suggested https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/4996